# HTML Submit button don't work

Tags: html

I recently started HTML and made my first Website. I made bunch of lines of codes, and the last line is: `<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" action="Registered.html">`. I wanted to this `submit` button named as "Register" to get me to the my "Registered.html" file but something isn't right. The button shows up, and it's valued as "Register" but `action="Registered.html" doesn't work. I hope you understand me, if you can, fix this for me.

Comment: `action="Registrered.html"` is something you should put on a `<form>`. Add an `<a>` element to your button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form element takes the action attribute, not the input:

```
<form action="Registered.html">
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

notice the action is at the form..

refer https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

Answer (score 0):

In general `form` elements are used to send data to a server. It wraps around the elements which specifies the data, `input` or `button` elements, for instance. If you add a `name` and a `value` attribute to your input and button elements, you will send this *name-value-pair* to your server.

If you don’t need to send any (additional) data to your server, just use anchor elements:

```
<a href="Registered.html">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>

<input type="submit" formaction="Registered.html" value="Register">
</form>
```

**The formaction attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.**